# Regex for any number greater or smaller than 0 but the number can begin with a 0

Tags: regex, bash

The easiest solution I found would be:

```
[^0]+
```

The main problem with this is that it doesn't match numbers that begin with a '0' e.g. '0123'. In addition to that it's very general and would match everything that isn't '0' including letters and special characters.

**Edit:**

Here's the whole script, maybe this helps finding a solution:

```
search=$(find / -iname _instanceBackup.log 2>/dev/null)
mytail=$(tail -n 14 $search)
mydate=$(date -dyesterday +%y%m%d)

if [[ $mytail =~ $mydate ]]
then
        echo "Backup is up to date!"
        mytail=${mytail,,}
        if [[ ( $mytail =~ 'failed' ) || ( $mytail =~ 'backupexitcode:'[missing RegEx] ) ]]
        then
                echo "An error has occurred in the backup!"
                        exit 1001
        else
                echo "No errors were found in the last backup."
                        exit 0
        fi
else
        echo "Backup hasn't run!"
                exit 1002
fi
```

The 2nd if-statement is what I'm trying to do with RegEx. Unfortunately I don't know exactly which backupexitcodes are possible but from recent logs I can say that they are 2-digit numbers that can be negative and can begin with a 0.

`$mytail` looks like this:

```
----------------------------
run_backup.sh(24778) 220222-200037: Instance:user@server:port Schema:"backupname" [Additional Information]
run_backup.sh(24778) 220222-200037: Instance:user@server:port Schema:"backupname" [Additional Information]
run_backup.sh(24778) 220222-200037: Instance:user@server:port Schema:"backupname" [Additional Information]
run_backup.sh(24778) 220222-200037: Instance:user@server:port Schema:"backupname" [Additional Information]
INFO         SAP BACKUP UTILITY
INFO         Creating backup of server [server:port] in folder [Backupfolder].
INFO         Server backup operations finished without error.
run_backup.sh(24778) 220222-200056: Instance:user@server:port Schema:"backupname" [Additional Information]
INFO         SAP BACKUP UTILITY
INFO         Older backups were deleted without error.
run_backup.sh(24778) 220222-200140: Instance:user@server:port Schema:"backupname" Finish: Timestamp:220222_200037 BackupExitCode:58
----------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is to match a digit only string with at least one non-zero digit? `^0*[1-9][0-9]*$`? Or, with `-`: ``^-?0*[1-9][0-9]*$``?

Comment: A little more info about the use-case may help.  For example - you said it can be smaller than 0 - so as @WiktorStribiżew said you may need the -? at the start.  Separately, is "00" or "000" acceptable"?

Based on your specific use-case, there may be a nicer way to frame the problem - but very likely I think Wiktor's suggestion will help you.

Comment: Which if any of the following are possible inputs: `-0`, `-00`, `00`, `-000`, `000`?

Comment: @chrisputnam9 I updated my question, maybe it's easier to understand now. "00" or "000" shouldn't be matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 's soltution seems to be working atlest when testing with [link](regexr.com)

Comment: Ok, what about the code? How are you planning to use it? `rx='^-?0*[1-9][0-9]*$'; if [[ "$text" =~ $rx ]]; then ... fi`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah something like that. I have tried implementing the regex directly into the if-statement as follows `if [[ ( $mytail =~ 'failed' ) || ( $mytail =~ "backupexitcode:"^-?0*[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]` but that isn't working. I'm not really sure if I have to put it in brackets or something?

Comment: Try `rx='backupexitcode:-?0*[1-9][0-9]*([^0-9]|$)'; if [[ "$mytail" == *failed* || "$mytail" =~  $rx ]]`.... What does the `mytail` look like?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works perfectly. I added a reconstruction of `$mytail` to the question. Should I add this as an answer and mention you or do you prefer to add it yourself so I could mark it as an accepted answer?

Comment: I hope my answer is complete enough. Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to match a numeric string that is not all zeros you can use

```
^-?0*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Here,  `^`  matches the string start  position, `-?` matches an optional `-`, then `0*` matches zero or more `0` digits, a `[1-9]` pattern matches a non-zero digit and then `[0-9]*` matches zero or more digits and `$` asserts the position at the end of string.

You can use

```sh
rx='backupexitcode:-?0*[1-9][0-9]*([^0-9]|$)'
if [[ "$mytail" == *failed* || "$mytail" =~  $rx ]]; then
# the rest of the script
```

*Regex details*:

- `backupexitcode:` - a literal `backupexitcode:` string
- `-?` - an optional `-` char
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `[0-9]*` - any zero or more digits
- `([^0-9]|$)` - a non-digit char or end of string.

The `"$mytail" == *failed*` part is using a glob, not a regex pattern, `*` wildcard matches any zero or more chars and the glob pattern must match the whole string (hence, `*` on both ends are required as `failed` should be detected anywhere inside the `mytail` string).

Comment: I noticed that you changed some small things in the if-statement. Is there some noteworthy difference between using `=~ 'failed'` and `== *failed*`?

Comment: @Icoryx Globs matching with `==` is faster than regex matching with `=~`.